# Custom model editing for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a `Book` model in Rails, and this model as a resources has predefined routes e.g. `/books/:id/edit`.

Now, in my app I wish to show a list of books and add an edit button where everyone can edit the book but only one specific field. I wish to achieve this by rendering a different view, using a different route and a different controller.

How should I define the route so that this works, i.e. the id of the Book instance is passed as needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can keep

```bash
rails g model book field_one field_two
rails g controller books
```

```rb
# routes.rb
resources :books
patch 'common_update/:id', to: 'books#common_update'
```

if you specifically want to hit another controller then you can just create a different one (`rails g contoller_name`) and replace **books** in the routes with **contoller_name** (note that the generator takes a plural!).

```rb
# books_controller.rb
def common_update
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.update(common_params)
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end

def common_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:field_one) # but not field_two !
end
```

As for views, you can perhaps conditionally render the form for the owner (the user who created the book) and the form for everyone else. If you want a separate view/show you can also just add the route (`get 'common_show', to: 'controller_name#common_show'`) plus a view file in the correct folder :+1:

Comment: It seems rails is reporting common_edit_path does not exist... am I missing something?

Comment: you can add ```as: :common_edit``` so that it looks like this: ```patch 'common_edit/:id', to: 'books#common_edit', as: 'common_edit'``` that should defo work. also noticed that its probs best to call it **update** not **edit** but yeah... ill change it in the answer